# Question about Loop Limit in VBA (Excel Macro)

Tags: excel, vba, loops, nested, limit

To preface my code could be simpler and better made without a doubt. Nevertheless, it does the job and works perfectly except for a hard loop limit that it encounters. In short the objective is to write down dates for a given store and loop through all the dates in a store. See Image 1 for the example input
[Example 1 - Input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RUuWr.png) Now the output data only needs to return the dates in a column. I have other parts of the code that formats and fixes things already so this portion only needs to write the dates 1 per column, See sample output in Example 2 [Example 2 - Desired Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XrieH.png)

Again, the code works well, except that it runs into a problem and won't output past 373 rows and I know there are limits but I would have expected numbers well into the thousands for a simple nested loop. Now that is for the Unique Store IDs, For the other data it's checking against it stops around roughly 1469 rows. A bigger number, but from what I could research online I shouldn't be hitting any limits just quite yet. Is there something I am utilizing incorrectly to increase my limit? I apologize for any errors in formatting as I am new to coding & to the stacked overflow community.

```
Sub MissingDates()
'SubRoutine to check for missing Dates
Dim store As String
Dim storeunique As String
Dim missdat As String
Dim str As String
'Store = Store_ID; missdat = missing Date; Storeunique = Nonduplicate store column

'cel As Range
Dim i As Integer
Dim x As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim n As Integer
Dim a As Integer


x = 1
'x = 253
j = 0
'j = 150
i = 1

For i = 1 To 400


    store = Range("A" & x + 3).Value
    storeunique = Range("E" & i + 3).Value
    If storeunique = "" Then
        Exit For
    ElseIf store = storeunique Then
        For n = 1 To 31
        'n - Column of Dates to be checked against
            store = Range("A" & x + 3).Value

            If store = storeunique Then
                missdat = Range("B" & x + 3).Value
                a = Len(missdat)
                str = Left(missdat, a - 5)

                Cells(j + 4, n + 6).Value = str
            Else
                Exit For
            End If
            '
            x = x + 1
        Next n

    End If
        j = j + 1

Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: First step, use `Long` instead of `Integer`.

Comment: You have two `Exit For` statements.  It is possible those conditions were met.

Comment: It just stops?  No error messages or any indication of a problem?

Comment: hi. put a `Debug.Print` before the `exit for` to see if you reached an exit condition

Answer (score 0):

From reviewing your code and the details that you've given, it is most likely that you are hitting the exit condition of:

```
If storeunique = "" Then
    Exit For
```

Have you checked that when you're assigning the 'storeunique' value, you're not running into a blank cell unexpectedly?

You're right that for the amount of rows (1469 from your original post) is far below the maximum integer value of 32,767 (more on data values from Microsoft's documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/data-type-summary).) If this were the case, you would encounter an overflow error.